# UTF-8 with jsp servlet

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, utf-8

I want to display hindi text in text box of jsp coming from servlet try all 
but not helpful

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: I submit a request and get string in hindi but it display as ?????

Comment: Try response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8"); in Servlet.